# I have the site-packages for Python 3.8 but not the interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, interpreter, site-packages

I have this path in my mac:
`/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` but I don't have `/usr/local/bin/python3.8`, which should be the interpreter.

Currently, my `pip3 install` command would install packages into `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`, but I can't use python3.8 since I don't have the interpreter. I don't care which version of python I use. I just want to install packages into the directory that I can use.

So please help me with one of the questions:

1. Install Python 3.8 interpreter so I can use packages installed by pip3.

OR

2. Change the default pip3 installation path to other directory such as `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` which I already have.

Answer (score 0):

You could do one of them.
Install python 3.8 should solve your problem

or

Have you tried to rename the **python3.8** to **python3.7**?
(Make sure you have python 3.7, by clicking "python3 --version" in terminal)

> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages ->
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages